# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, sqlcommand

My code throws this error mentioned in the subject. I don't know the origin because using ODBC to connect to mysql it works, but using SQL do connect to SQL Server Express doesn't work. How to fix it?

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("insert into lojas (NIF, Loja, bloqueado, DataFim, lastupdate, Nome) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", connection);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIF", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loja", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);        
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bloqueado", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFim", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastupdate", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);

connection.Open();
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` is not valid parameter placeholder in SQL Server's t-sql syntax. You need to update your query to have named parameters:

```
insert into lojas (NIF, Loja, bloqueado, DataFim, lastupdate, Nome) 
values (@NIF, @Loja, @Bloqueado, @DataFim, @lastupdate, @Nome)
```

When you are adding the parameter values, the name of the parameter used in the `AddWithValue` call will be used to put the value in the correct place in the query.

Comment: I think that was the problem, but now another came up when I insert the data: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Licenciamento.dbo.lojas'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." But the Id is set as auto-incrementable in sql server. Shouldn't it be automatically filled in the datagrid?